# Image not displayed in Table (Oracle JET ojTable component)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I was trying to display an image in an HTML table using Oracle JET I had written this in the backing JavaScript file:

```
var image = document.createElement("IMG"),
image.setAttribute("src", "../../../status_up.png");
self.listData.push({
                        Status: image
                    });
```

In HTML, the code went like this:

```
<table id="test_table"
   data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojTable', 
                            data: datasource, 
                            scrollPolicy: 'loadMoreOnScroll',
                            selectionMode: {row: 'single', column: 'single'},
                            columnsDefault: {sortable: 'enabled'}, 
                            columns: [{headerText: 'Status',
                                       field: 'Status'}]
                            rootAttributes: {'style':'width: 100%; height: 230px;'}}">
```

The Table is displayed properly, but the column where it should show the image, it shows this:

```
[object HTMLImageElement]
```

Snapshot

I saw that the Image URL is formed properly, and when I went to the Image URL, I was able to download and see the image. But it doesn't show up in the HTML Table. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Oracle JET forum for questions and discussions:

https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/oracle-jet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520553/swipe-to-reveal-is-not-working .Can you please help me to solve this one??

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom row template: [custom_row](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=table&demo=customRowTable)

then in the column, you can put any html attribute. In this case, you can put img attribute with src url.